# WPF Binding TextBlock to ProgressBar with Percentage

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, textbox, progress-bar

I have a ProgressBar which has a maximum of 10,000 (not 100).  I want the binded TextBox to show the percentage of the current Value, not the Value itself.  Is it possible to do this in the .xaml code?

The following shows the current Value of my ProgressBar.  I want it to show the Value / Maximum.

```
        <ProgressBar x:Name="calculationProgressBar" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="calculationProgressText" Text="{Binding ElementName=calculationProgressBar, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}" />
```

Comment: Xaml does not do calculations; that function is performed either through converters or property binding.

Answer (score 3):

You could setup a simple `IMultiValueConverter` and pass in the `ProgressBars` `Value` and `Maximum` properties

Example:

Converter

```
public class ValueToPercentConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double value = System.Convert.ToDouble(values[0]);
        double maximum = System.Convert.ToDouble(values[1]);
        return (value / maximum) * 100;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="100">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ValueToPercentConverter x:Key="ValueToPercentConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="calculationProgressBar" Maximum="10000" Value="2566" Height="40"/>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ValueToPercentConverter}" StringFormat="{}{0}">
                    <Binding ElementName="calculationProgressBar" Path="Value"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="calculationProgressBar" Path="Maximum"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since manipulations are not possible in XAML so converters is a approach for the same

I tried to write a simple code for you, using string format for percent notice `StringFormat={}{0:P0}`

XAML example

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <l:ScaleConverter x:Key="ScaleConverter"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Slider x:Name="calculationSource" Maximum="10000"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=calculationSource, 
                              Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:P0}, 
                              Converter={StaticResource ScaleConverter}, 
                              ConverterParameter=10000}" />
</StackPanel>
```

I used slider instead of progressbar for easy demo, you can use any source

specify the max value in converter parameter

and P0 in string format means percentage format with 0 precision eg 0%, you can choose to make it P1 for 1 decimal and so on eg 0.0%

converter class

```cs
class ScaleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToDouble(value) / System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

converter is pretty simple, divide the value by the defined scale.

I hope you'll find it useful for your issue

**Extras**

additionally if you prefer to define the max range at a single location you can use resources for the same

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <l:ScaleConverter x:Key="ScaleConverter"/>
        <sys:Double x:Key="maxRange">10000</sys:Double>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Slider x:Name="calculationSource" Maximum="{StaticResource maxRange}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=calculationSource, 
               Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:P0}, 
               Converter={StaticResource ScaleConverter}, 
               ConverterParameter={StaticResource maxRange}}" />
</StackPanel>
```